# How to write a message to dmesg at beginning?

Tags: linux

Currently upon boot when I run `dmesg | head` I get.

```
[    0.000000] Linux version 4.17.19+ (bob@bob-VirtualBox) (gcc version 7.3.0 (Ubuntu          7.3.0-16ubuntu3)) #2 SMP Mon Sep 10 21:33:25 EDT 2018
[    0.000000] Command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-4.17.19+ root=UUID=2e69cd99-b344-4014-bb00-ce3da383be05 ro quiet splash
[    0.000000] KERNEL supported cpus:
```

etc...

Is there an already existing file in the kernel source I can modify to print a message like "Hello world" so it shows up at the beginning or after the the first line of the dmesg output after a boot once I have built and installed the new kernel. I realize I can do this via a new module but is there something I can modify that pre-exists?

Answer (score 1):

You can modify the function which prints the first lines of output; it’s `start_kernel` in [`init/main.c`](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/init/main.c). The “Linux version” message is stored in `linux_banner` and output [using `pr_notice`](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/init/main.c?id=3f5c15d8a7d86fb642fe07df58c2065190f3e531#n551), which you should use too for early messages.

Answer (score 0):

Edit the root crontab:

```
# crontab -e
```

Add the following line:

```
@reboot  echo "Hello World!" > /dev/kmsg
```

Reboot then check :

```
# dmesg | grep Hello
```